# propagation of the error in the summation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-error, error, computational-statistics, error-propagation

I have a question regarding the propagation of the error during the summation. Please see the equation below. In this equation only quantity R has an error. How it will propagate to the final value $P_{total}$?

$P_{total} = \frac{\sum \limits_i (S)_i (\frac{3}{R+2})_i (N)_i (1-R)_i}{\sum \limits_i (S)_i (\frac{3}{R+2})_i (N)_i}$

Comment: Welcome to CV! In your posts you can use TeX formatting for equations, e.g. \frac{a}{b} (closed in two dolar signs on both sides) gives you $\frac{a}{b}$. See more here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics